# is this the correct way to solve the question?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 35 students in David's homeroom class. There are 5 students who take English and Biology,and 7 students who take neither of these subjects.There are 3 more students taking English only than there are students taking biology only. 
The number of students in David's homeroom class who take English only is?

my work:

35 students in Davids homeroom
5 students take English and biology 
7 students take neither subjects
3 more take English than there are taking biology

5+7=12-3=9 students who take English only

is this the correct way to solve it,if not whats a correct solution to solve this question?

Comment: You could try Venn's diagrams for visualization.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin, I think you mean a Venn diagram. But yes, that would work. I assume that there are only two options for classes -- i.e., English and biology -- in which case some careful labelling will do the trick.

Comment: Corrected, thank you. You mean labelling [like this](https://i.imgur.com/n8kXIBQ.png)?

Answer (score 2):

The total number of students is $35$ and  $35-7=28$ students are taking at least one class.  $28-5=23$ students are taking only one class. $23$ students are taking ONLY Biology or ONLY English: $23=B+E \implies 23=B+B+3 \implies B=10$.  Therefore, $13$ students take ONLY English.  $13+5=\boxed{18}$ students take English as a class.